# Contar etiquetas que contengan un string

Tags: xml, xpath

Tengo un fichero XML y necesito saber el total de etiquetas  que contienen la cadena 'KO' con Xpath.`

He probado `count(/estados/Result/text = 'KO')` pero me devuelve `'Not a node set in function count'`

```
<estados>
  <Result>KO</Result>
  <Result>OK</Result>
  <Result>OK</Result>
  <Result>KO</Result>
</estados>
```

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 especialmente puntos 2, 3 y 4.

Answer (score 0):

[[image: .]
Es el xml con la funcion Xpath que he probado para contar las etiquetas que contienen la cadena 'KO', como puedo saber el total de etiquetas que contienen la cadena 'KO'